# Permission Store not installed in JBoss Seam

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, seam2

I use Eclipse Helios (JBoss Tools installed) with JBoss 5.1 GA and Seam 2.2. I noticed that each time my project is being deployed, I see a warning telling me that no permission store is installed. Install permission store if you want to use persistent connections

Please how to do I make use of the default permission store that comes with the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in section `15.6.10.3. JpaPermissionStore` of seam [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html_single/)

The main point there is that you assign a special entity, that will be responsible to provide and store authorization data. Seam will scan annotations `org.jboss.seam.annotations.security.permission.*` on fields of the entity and decide how to use or set the values of that fields.

Also note that Seam won't provide you UI to manage the permission store, instead it will give APIs, which you use to build your own.

I haven't found a good example on how to use this feature of Seam, but `seamspace` example coming with Seam should give you a starting point on how to use `Seam Security`.